# For loop Lists function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def f(p):
    z=len(p)
    for y in range(0,z):
        if "t" in p[y]:
            print(p[y])
    return
list = ["titan","ton", "automatic","manual"]
f(list)
```

The function is supposed to remove all words that begin with the letter ‘t’ from the list.  The function then returns that list. This function just returns a list with all words with t in them.

Comment: It doesn't return anything.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name!

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is twofold:

1. You are not removing the items from the list in your function.
2. You are not returning anything from the function; namely, the filtered list.

However, you don't need a function that big for this job.  Just use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter out those items:

```
>>> lst = ["titan","ton", "automatic","manual"]
>>> def func(lst):
...     # You could also do `[x for x in lst if not x.lower().startswith("t")]`
...     # which will also capture words starting with "T"
...     return [x for x in lst if not x.startswith("t")]
...
>>> # Reassign 'lst' to the cleaned list
>>> lst = func(lst)
>>> lst
['automatic', 'manual']
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your function returns `None`, although it prints out all the words with `"t"` in them.  What you want is something like

```
def f(p):
    no_ts = []
    for el in p:
        if not el.startswith("t"):
            no_ts.append(el)
    return no_ts
```

It can be easily done with a list comprehension

```
[el for el in p if not el.lower().startswith("t")]
# .lower() makes sure to catch words that start with "T"
```

Also, it's best if you don't confuse the namespace by naming variables with reserved names like "list" or "str".

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning a list at all, you're just printing its items.

Secondly there's no need to use indexes to iterate over list items, simply iterate over the list itself.

Solution using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def f(p):
    return [item for item in p if item.startswith('t')]

lis = ["titan","ton", "automatic","manual"]
new_lis = f(lis)
print(new_lis)
#['titan', 'ton']
```

You can make your code work by simply replacing the `print` call with `yield` and making a few other changed. Using `yield` makes this function a [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
def f(p):
    for item in p:
        if item.startswith('t'):
            yield item
...             
>>> list(f(lis))  #call list on the generator expression returned by `f` to see its content
['titan', 'ton']
```

---

Note that `in` operator is used for substring match, so:

```
>>> "t" in "automatic"
True
```

is `True`, if you want to check just the first character then use `str.startswith`:

```
>>> "automatic".startswith('t')
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use filter:

```
>>> li=["titan","ton", "automatic","manual"]
>>> filter(lambda s: not s.startswith('t'), li)
['automatic', 'manual']
```